# Prove that $3\mathbb{Z}$ with the 3 - adic metric is clopen set

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(\mathbb{Z} , d_3)$ be the integer space with 3 - adic metric.
I need to prove that the set $3\mathbb{Z}$ is open and closed set.

In order to prove that the set is open, I took $3z\in 3 \mathbb{Z}$ and tried to prove that $\exists r>0$ such that for every $x\in \mathbb{R}$ that makes $d_3(3z,x) \leq r$ we get that $x\in \mathbb{3Z}$.

But, this way of proving it looks too complicated to me, and there is gotta be other way which is easier. Could you help me prove that this set is open?

Comment: Try $r = \frac 13$.